error writing flutter unit tests for an SQLite database API
I'm trying to write a test file for my flutter database API. I have a prepopulated database on which I want to execute my tests that is stored in assets/database/ and is named database.db.
pubspec.yaml:
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite_common_ffi: ^2.3.3

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/database/

database_api.dart:
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseAPI {
  static final DatabaseAPI _instance = DatabaseAPI._internal();
  static Database? _db;
  final String _dbName = "database.db";

  DatabaseAPI._internal();

  factory DatabaseAPI() {
    return _instance;
  }

  Future<Database?> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    } else {
      _db = await _initDB();
      return _db;
    }
  }

  Future<Database> _initDB() async {
    final path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), _dbName);
    final exist = await databaseExists(path);
    if(!exist) {
      try {
        ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join('assets', 'database', _dbName));
        List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
        await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
      } catch (error) {
        throw Exception('Error copying database: $error');
      }
    }
    return await openDatabase(path);
  }

  Future<String> fetchLanguage() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    final List<Map<String, Object?>> list = await dbClient!.query('language');
    var lang = list[0]['selected'];
    return lang.toString();
  }
}

This is how I write my test file
database_api_test.dart:
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:drinking_game/db_api/database_api.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';

void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;

  test('fetchLanguage returns correct data', () async {
    var api = DatabaseAPI();
    var lang = await api.fetchLanguage();
    print(lang);
    expect(lang, "Italiano");
  });
}

The error that is generated is:
Exception: Error copying database: Unable to load asset: "assets\database\database.db".
  The asset does not exist or has empty data.
  package:drinking_game/db_api/new_database_api.dart 49:9  DatabaseAPI._initDB

But this error arise just when I run the test, when I do a normal build I have no error. How can I solve this?

The test environment is not a normal app environment, which is why you are seeing this issue when testing.  You need to do one or both of the following:

Define the test as a Widgets test by using testWidgets('myTest', (tester) instead of test('myTest', ()
In your setUp method, copy the files you want to access in your tests from the assets directory to an accessible directory, e.g.

    // copy the test database files from assets to documents directory
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    for (final filename in [db1, db2, db3]) {
      var uploadFilePath = join(directory.path, filename);
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/$filename");
      final buffer = data.buffer;
      File(uploadFilePath).writeAsBytesSync(
          buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
    }

